# PHP - Client receiving spam from contact form despite anti spam measures

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email-validation

On my clients website there is a contact form. They have said that they are getting a lot of spam through to them despite several anti spam measures put in place.

Front end form:

```
   <p class="st-address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>COMPANY<br/>Office<br/>Something Road<br/>Town<br/>Postcode</p>
   <p class="st-phone"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>123456</p>
   <p class="st-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             var first = "info";
             var last = "something.com";
             document.write(first + '@' + last);
          </script>
  </p>


   <form action="php/send-contact.php" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Name*">
   <input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email*">
   <p class="antispam"> <input type="text" name="url"/></p>
   <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Site" required="required">
   <textarea name="message" required="required" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message*">Home</textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-send">
   </form>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '' ){

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'hello@email.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Site: ' . $website . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $body, 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Site: ' . $website . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message);
}


?>
```

I changed the email address to my own to receive the spam emails to see if they were coming from a particular page (I put the name of the page a s the value in the message field temporarily).... And I have received no spam emails at all.

Before I changed the email address to my own the client received one with the message value indicating that it had come from the homepage so it definitely was spam from the contact form but I am receiving literally nothing and don't know why. There's nothing in my spam folder either.

Anyone any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: you can't really stop spam, since some of them are actual humans. you can try honeycomb or captcha though.

Comment: u may also use the google recaptcha

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile They arent keen on captcha unfortunately

Comment: @hungrykoala I would bet that its a spam bot from the emails they have received. Client not keen on captcha

Comment: From my experience what we did was that we would add a hidden text field inside the form and give it a default value, and when the form is submitted we would check if that value was changed or not. if that was changed chances are that the spam bot filled that field with random strings so we will know that submission was a spam.

Comment: @spbrad then add honeyport field

Comment: @hungrykoala yeah I have a hidden field that is blank and it will not send if this field is filled. unfortunately not working!

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yeah there is already a hidden field!

Comment: @spbrad how about create a field but hide it using dsiplay:none instead. maybe bots are getting smarter?

Comment: @spbrad I do not see any hidden field in that form

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile <p class="antispam"> <input type="text" name="url"/></p> is the hidden field.

Comment: @spbrad bots are smarter than that.. what u can do add a checkbox, then make it invisible by css, add default value, autocomplete off,  tabindex-1

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile cool i'll try that